# Primitive types are not traited Immutable in scala?

Tags: scala

Can anyone please share insight into the trait "Immutable" in scala? At first glance I thought this would be a nice control structure to limit a class I'm building, but oddly I noticed that primitive types do not extend this. Is there a reason for this? Is there a way to bind the syntax to Immutable or AnyVal?

```
class Test {

  def test[T<:Immutable](x:T)={
   println("passes "+x)

 }
  case class X(s:String) extends Immutable

  test(X("hello")) //passes
  // test("fail")  - does not pass compiler

}
```

Comment: `java.lang.String` is not a primitive type; since it is defined by Java, Scala can only work around it to provide functionality. See: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString

Comment: good point but what about Int? It extends Scala invented type traits such as "AnyVal" could they not have tagged AnyVal as immutable for consistency?

Comment: I suspect that `Immutable` was actually defined to identify mutable data-structures like map, set, list, etc... with respect to their mutable counterparts. It was not intended for generic classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only direct subtypes of `Immutable` in the Scala core library are:

- `collection.immutable.Traversable`
- `collection.parallel.immutable.ParIterable`

Nothing else refers to `Immutable` at all.

`Immutable` [hasn't been changed](https://github.com/scala/scala/commits/master/src/library/scala/Immutable.scala) since it was added in 2009 in Martin Odersky's "[massive new collections checkin](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/14a631a5fec42d04d0723355a0b93e482b5e4662)". I'm searching through that commit, and it looks like `Immutable` was never even used as a bound when it was first introduced either.

Honestly, I doubt there's much intent behind these traits anymore. Odersky probably planned to use `Immutable` to bound the type arguments on immutable collections, and then thought better of it. But that's just my speculation.

Answer (score 2):

So-called primitive types (Boolean, Byte, Char, Short, Int, Long, Float, Double) are intrinsically immutable. 5 is 5 is 5. You cannot do anything to 5 to turn it into anything that is not 5.

Otherwise, immutability is a property of how a value is stored. If stored in a `var`, that `var` may be replaced freely with a new value (of a compatible type). By extension, constructed types (`class`es, `trait`s and `object`s) may be either immutable or mutable depending on whether they allow any of their internal state to be altered following construction.

Java's `String` (also used as Scala's `String`) is immutable.

However, none of this has anything to do with you example, since you did not demonstrate mutability. You simply showed what happens when one applies the `+` method of one value to another value.

While it is certainly possible that one can implement a `+` method that mutates its (apparent) left-hand operand, one rarely does that. If there's a need for that kind of mutation, one would conventionally define the `+=` method instead.

`+` is somewhat special in that it may be applied to any value (if the argument / right-hand operand) is a `String` by virtue of an implicit conversion to a special class that defines `+(s: String)` so that the string concatenation interpretation of `+` may be applied. In other words, if you write `e1 + "e2"` and the type of the expression `e1` does not define `+`, then Scala will convert `e1` to `String` and concatenate it with `"e2"`.